# Load images from local disk

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-vue

I currently get my hands on electron with the electron-vue boilerplate.

My goal is to show all images from a given folder in the application (renderer process).

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="selectSourceDir()">Quellverzeichnis</button>
    Aktuell: {{sourcePath}}
    <button @click="scan()">Aktualisieren</button>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="image in images">
        <!--<img v-bind:src="'data:image/jpg;base64,' + image.base64">-->
        <img v-bind:src="'file://' + image.path">
      </li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ImageFile from './ImageDispatchPage/ImageFile';
  import fs from 'fs';
  import { ipcRenderer as ipc } from 'electron';
  import path from 'path';

  export default {
    name: 'image-dispatch-page',
    components: { ImageFile },
    data () {
      return{
        images: [],
        sourcePath: null,
      }  
    },
    methods: {     
      scan(){        
        // If path is not set do nothing
        if(!this.sourcePath){
          return;
        }
        // Iterate over all files in directory
        let files = fs.readdirSync(this.sourcePath);
        const regex = /.jpe?g$/gmi;        
        for (let file of files){          
          // Ignore non jpg files                    
          if(!file.match(regex)){
            continue;                                    
          }          
          let image = {};
          image.name = file;
          image.path = path.join(this.sourcePath, file);
          image.base64 = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(image.path)).toString('base64');       
          this.images.push(image);
        }        
      },
      selectSourceDir(){
        ipc.send('open-directory-dialog');        
        ipc.on('selected-directory', (event, directory) => {
          this.sourcePath = directory;         
        });        
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.scan();
    } 
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  
</style>
```

Running this code results in the following error message: [image: error]
Everything works if I use the commented out line with base64 encoded images which is very very slow (line 8).

What is the proper solution to simply show these images?

Comment: Use the relative file path to the image, not a URL (I did not downvote)

Comment: I tried to determine the relative path for the image with app.getAppPath() and nodes path.relative (not sure if this is what you meant) - which gave me the relative path but the error message showing in the console remains the same: "Not allowed to load local resoucre"

Comment: Turn web security off: `"web-preferences": {
      "web-security": false
    }`

Comment: Thank you Randy! A quick look at the docs revealed a different notation with the current version. Are there any security concerns with this setting?

Comment: Security depends upon what you are doing with the app. If you are only loading resources that you control as part of your app, then no, there isn't really a security concern. Otherwise there can be.

Comment: "safer" way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393845/electron-load-remote-url-and-load-local-file

Documentation: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md

Comment: Unfortunately this results in my case also in the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning off web security in my main process did the trick.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 563,
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 1000,
    webPreferences: {
        webSecurity: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Adding a note here that you should think hard about whether you really want to disable this option: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#6-do-not-disable-websecurity

"Disabling webSecurity will disable the same-origin policy and set allowRunningInsecureContent property to true. In other words, it allows the execution of insecure code from different domains."