# "Not allowed to load local resource" with file image URL in Electron app

Tags: electron

I am working on a note taking Electron app that uses Markdown. Currently, I'm working on inserting images into notes (using the Markdown syntax).

When inserting an image, my main process copies the image into the notes directory, then returns a `file:///` URL to the image file. However, when I try to render the image, it doesn't load - and I get the error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Users/joe/notes/images/foo.jpg`.

Is there a way I can configure Electron to allow these local image URLs?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Turning the web security off

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  height: 563,
  useContentSize: true,
  width: 1000,
  webPreferences: {
    webSecurity: false
}
});
```

**Option 2**

You can create your own protocol [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393845/electron-load-remote-url-and-load-local-file)

Also here is the [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74264/bvurvkyuvlvivic7) that answered that question

Comment: Turning off security shouldn't be an answer in any case

Answer (score 1):

You need register a file protocol to remove the `file:///` prefix.

```js
import { protocol } from "electron";

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  protocol.registerFileProtocol('file', (request, callback) => {
    const pathname = decodeURI(request.url.replace('file:///', ''));
    callback(pathname);
  });
});
```

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23757#issuecomment-640146333