# What to use now that "registerFileProtocol" is Deprecated in Electron?

Tags: electron, vuejs3, deprecated

**My original problem**

I am building a vue.js 3 desktop app with Electron as the wrapper. I need to load images from the users storage and display them in the app, but I keep getting a `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/.../somename.jpg` error. I looked it up and found this:

["Not allowed to load local resource" with file image URL in Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58385872/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-with-file-image-url-in-electron-app)

It seems the only way (other than turning off `webSecurity`) to get around the error is to make your own custom file protocol.

**My new problem and question**

All the answers and examples I can find online all use `protocol.registerFileProtocol`, which is [deprecated](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol#protocolregisterfileprotocolscheme-handler-deprecated) (I also found examples using `interceptFileProtocol` which is also [deprecated](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol#protocolinterceptstringprotocolscheme-handler-deprecated), and `registerBufferProtocol` which is [deprecated](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol#protocolregisterbufferprotocolscheme-handler-deprecated) as well).

How do I make a custom file protocol in electron without using the deprecated  methods? I'm very new to Electron. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Deprecated in Electron 25
protocol.registerFileProtocol('some-protocol', () => {
  callback({ filePath: '/path/to/my/file' })
})

// Replace with
protocol.handle('some-protocol', () => {
  return net.fetch('file:///path/to/my/file')
})
```

Reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#deprecated-protocolregisterinterceptbufferstringstreamfilehttpprotocol

Answer (score 0):

The error you get only occurs when your `BrowserWindow` displays its content using [`loadURL`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsloadurlurl-options). If in production your window displays a local HTML using [`loadFile`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsloadfilefilepath-options), the easiest solution is to disable `webSecurity` but only in dev:

```js
webPreferences: {
  webSecurity: app.isPackaged,
  allowRunningInsecureContent: false // Optional, save you from a warning in dev
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, if you really need a custom protocol, the official replacement for the deprecated methods is [`protocol.handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol#protocolhandlescheme-handler), as specified in the [breaking changes of v25](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#deprecated-protocolregisterinterceptbufferstringstreamfilehttpprotocol).

Comment: If you turn off `webSecurity` in dev wouldn't you still have the error in production? I'm loading images from storage almost like a file explorer would. I guess I'm not sure how `webSecurity` really works.

Comment: @sundrycode `webSecurity` enables the same-origin policy, so you can't load a local file from `file://` when you're on `localhost` for example. I had a custom protocol before v25 and now I just have `webSecurity` disabled in dev. It works fine in production because I'm loading my HTML locally (same origin as the files). So a custom protocol is useless in this case. You can try yourself and see if it works for you.

Comment: It works very nicely (especially since I still can't get the protocol working:), but I get this message: `Electron Security Warning (allowRunningInsecureContent) This renderer process has "allowRunningInsecureContent"
  enabled. This exposes users of this app to severe security risks.` Is that something to be concerned about?

Comment: @sundrycode From the docs: `webSecurity` "will disable the same-origin policy (usually using testing websites by people), and set `allowRunningInsecureContent` to `true` if this options has not been set by user". And [`allowRunningInsecureContent`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#8-do-not-enable-allowrunninginsecurecontent) prevents "websites loaded over `HTTPS` to load and execute scripts, CSS, or plugins from insecure sources (`HTTP`)". You should be able to disable it in dev if you want, but it will be disabled in prod anyway when `webSecurity` is enabled.

Comment: You can read about security [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security).